# Block plugin update possibilities (but not by hiding notifications)

Tags: plugins, php, functions, updates

Is it possible to block specific plugins from updating, manually too? I don't want to block this by hiding the notification, changing the plugin version or anything like this. I'd like the notification to show, show the new version number, but when hitting the update manually it should block/disallow this - preferably displaying some sort of (cusomized) notification in the plugin section (eg. "Update for this plugin is not possible").

Comment: if it's a free plugin of wordpress.org, you juste have to rename the directory name of the plugin.

Comment: I was more looking into commercial plugins.

Comment: there is a lot of different way to update a commercial plugin then you have to read the code of the plugin to find how to stop the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'http_request_args', 'dm_prevent_update_check', 10, 2 );
function dm_prevent_update_check( $r, $url ) {
    if ( 0 === strpos( $url, 'http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check/' ) ) {
        $my_plugin = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
        $plugins = unserialize( $r['body']['plugins'] );
        unset( $plugins->plugins[$my_plugin] );
        unset( $plugins->active[array_search( $my_plugin, $plugins->active )] );
        $r['body']['plugins'] = serialize( $plugins );
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897044/wordpress-how-to-disable-plugin-update

Comment: Useful link: https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/14/excluding-your-plugin-or-theme-from-update-checks/

Comment: This would work, but I don't want the plugin not to check and show updates. I want them visible but restrict the actual update process for manual updates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are still planning on updating plugins yourself but don't want other users to be able to do it, according to wp-admin/update.php you can revoke the 'update_plugins' permission from a user to prevent this. They will get a wp_die message 'Sorry, you are not allowed to update plugins for this site.'

For permissions management you can use [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) or similar.

Comment: Well, I'd need that option for admins as well. Deciding by role is nice and easy, but I need to achieve the same, but for all users. If I ever want to update plugins myself, I'd have to delete the extra code I've put there for this block to work...

Comment: Put every other admin but you in a lesser role without upgrade privilages. It seems like you're making this more complicated than it needs to be.